# Dynamic web content with VB6 (java servlet inspired)

Tags: com, vb6

I'm working on a project that needs more 'flare' than what can normally be done with VB6.  My thought is to generate HTML/CSS content and display this within a browser control on a form.  I would also like the ability to respond to form events from the web content within the VB application.  My inspiration comes from recent experience with java servlets and jps.  Has anyone done something similar?

I'm interested in what controls could be used to display the content and any suggestions on ways to interact with the page elements.  Generating the html and css should not be a problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Microsoft [Web Browser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085(VS.85).aspx) to embed Internet Explorer into your application. Then you may be able to implement two-way communication with the [BeforeNavigate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768326(VS.85).aspx) event: I believe [you can do it in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx).

An alternative way to get "flair" is to create a fancy form in .NET, perhaps using [WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/VB6InteropToolkit2.aspx), and then display it from a VB6 application using the [Interop Forms 2 Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb419144.aspx).

Comment: Be very careful about creating forms that have WPF on them with Interop Forms 2 Toolkit, much better to create a .Net control and host that on a VB6 form -- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/VB6InteropToolkit2.aspx (the threading between WPF/.Net and VB6 do crazy things that can lead to random form disappearance)